# Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables, Software Requirement?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When compiling with Visual Studio C++, I noticed that you need a specific MSV C++ Redist, depending on the version of Visual Studio you compile with. The required redistributable is necessary on machines without it. Otherwise without the redists missing MSVCPxxx.dll errors are prompt.

Is there a way to by-pass needing the necessity of the redistributable? Or is there a way to package that inside of the program you're creating, be it DLL, executable, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Statically linked executables don't need this redistributable.

You create statically linked executable by switching the runtime type from "Multi-threaded DLL" to "Multi-threaded" (compiler option `/MT` instead of `/MD`).

It is subject to the following limitations:

- All libraries the executable is linked to have to be compiled with the same setting. So if you use third-party libraries and don't have variant for static compilation nor sources, you can't get rid of the redistributable.
- Compiling shared libraries (DLL) with static runtime will cause problems due to multiple definitions of some things. In some cases with small interfaces the problems can be avoided, but most of the time it does not work. So if you need DLLs, you will probably need the redistributable too.

If you need the redistributable, the common option is to create installer that will include it.

It should be also possible to create a small starter that will install the redistributable (carried in resources) and than start the main program (also carried in resources, possibly as DLL to avoid new process). I've never done it. I know Python does it with the [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), but I don't know whether there is any simple wrapper for doing it with your own C++ program.

Comment: Good answer. This problem is not unique to C++ -- most computers don't have the latest .NET Framework either. Dealing with dependencies in the installer is just par for the course.